# Can't connect to MySQL server (60)

Tags: mysql, scala, heroku, playframework, cleardb

I added cleardb to my Heroku app.

config:

> CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://username:password@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/databse?reconnect=true
>
> DATABASE_URL:         mysql2://username:password@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/database?reconnect=true

Procfile:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/playeditor -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Ddb.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Dplay.crypto.secret=${APPLICATION_SECRET}
```

When I try to test the database connection(add server connection in MySQL Workbench) :

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net' (60)

And I tried another way:

```
mysql -u username -p -h us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net
```

I also get the same error.

The firewall is off from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

First, try using `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` instead like this:

```
web: ... -Ddb.default.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL} ...
```

If that still doesn't work, try using the [JawsDB add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb) instead of ClearDB. I have far fewer problems with it:

```
$ heroku addons:destroy DATABASE
$ heroku addons:create jawsdb:kitefin
```

You should not need to change any code for JawsDB.

Answer (score -2):

the hostname in your URL must be a real hostname, if your mysql is on local server it should be localhost or it should be the IP of remote server.

Comment: The host name is :us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net. So the error message is "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net' (60)"

Comment: Then check if your server had running a firewall and blocked the port 3306?

Comment: firewall was off from the beginning.